# Is it possible to access data given a list of column names in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My dataframe is as following:

```
    foo bar buzz

0   0.1  0.2  0.3
1   0.4  0.5  0.6
2   0.7  0.8  0.9
```

Now I have a list `['foo','bar','buzz']`
I want to get the right element at the right position row-wise,the result could be a series or something array-like `[0.1,0.5,0.9]`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `df[['foo','bar','buzz']]` ?

Comment: `df.lookup(*zip(*enumerate(l)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [`df.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
l=['foo','bar','buzz'] #your list
s=pd.Series(l) #create a series
df.lookup(s.index,s.values)
```

---

```
array([0.1, 0.5, 0.9])
```

Or with a list comprehension:

```
[df.loc[e,i] for e,i in enumerate(l)]
#or [df.iloc[e,df.columns.get_loc(i)] for e,i in enumerate(l)]
#[0.1, 0.5, 0.9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write:

```
Dataframe[[here the list of columns]]
```

and it will give you all the values of the column otherwise you have to iterate thru it using a for loop or list comprehension like this:

```
[row for row in dataframe[here the column names]]
```